# htaccess check if empty query string

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following situations on my server:

```
/->
  news-> 
    .htaccess
    index.php
    post.php
...
```

And the following rules in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule    ^(.*)/admin          post.php?slug=$1&admin_mode=true            [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule    ^(.*)$               post.php?slug=$1                            [NC,QSA,L]
```

Now I need my URLs to be the following:

> If requested www.mydomain.com/news/ -> it should get the index.php
>   file
>
> If requested www.mydomain.com/friendly-title-of-my-article -> it
>   should get the post.php file with the query string as indicated in my .htaccess.

Currently I get correctly the post.php with the query string, but when I go to www.mydomain.com/news/ , it's requesting the post.php file.

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to create nice routing is to let everything go to one `index.php` and control the flow there. It has multiple advantages like being able to query the database and then decide what page to load. That can influence SEO nicely.

Answer (score 6):

Use this

```
#if query string is empty

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$

#match on / for root, or .index.php in request and send to query string version 

RewriteRule ^(/|index.php)?$ /index.php?step=1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: already tried that.. it gets me to http://example.com/var/www/site/news/index.php?step=1 when requesting www.example.com/news/

Comment: this should be the answer. +1 for RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$

Comment: +1 for `(/|index.php)`, I had no clue I can do that in `.htaccess`. busted my head for 1 hour trying to redirect when no QUERY_STRING exists.